# How can I design UI like this?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

I have designed a UI in FIGMA that looks like the below image

[image]

And when I am trying the same in android studio, it doesn't look good.
Below is the code I am using

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dark"
        android:layout_width="364dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_layout"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/night"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

The UI looks like this

[image]

How can I achieve the design which I created using Figma?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use CardView to create this design its provide you rounded corner with shadow also use a custom drawable which have blue line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement the design, material card view provides you with most of the features.

- The Elevation: `app:cardElevation="dp"`
- The Outline :  `app:strokeWidth="dp"` specifying the width
- The Outline Color: `app:strokeColor="@color/"` specifying the color
- The Corner Radius: `app:cardCornerRadius="dp"` specifying the
  radius.

Like:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/corner_radius_8dp"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/elevation_4dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:strokeColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:strokeWidth="@dimen/stroke_width">

    <!--Content goes here-->

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks, It worked. Can you please do me another favor? Please tell me how to work with switches, it's my first time, and I have read online about it but didn't understand. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What would you like to know specifically? https://material.io/components/switches/android#switch provides a good start.

Comment: Thanks for your help and I have figured out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to create such type of UI in Android.

- You can create rounded drawable and place that drawable in background of image.
- You can group the box with text in Figma and then export the same UI and use it in android. (You need to create two UI (enable/disable).

I hope you understand what I want to say.

Thank you.

Comment: I tried the first point of your solution and it didn't help much. and can you please explain the 2nd point?

Comment: You have already create UI in Figma, so you just need to export whole Square with grouping as an image (png) and then you can use it in ImageView.